# Create node with taxonomy field using services in drupal 7

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, nodes, services

I am creating node from my android app using services 3. I hit this URL www.mysite/endpoint/node with the following json:

```
{
    "title": "my act for tax",
    "type": "activity",
    "field_activity_type": [{
        "tid": {
            "tid": "[tid:45]"
        }
    }]
}
```

`field_activity_type` is a taxonomy term autocomplete filed.

Node is created successfully but `field_activity_type` remains empty. I am unable to find a correct way to populate taxonomy field. 
Anyone who knows please help me.

Comment: Is it possible to send term (text) instead of term id in your json? If yes I'll post solution ;)
In that case we can easily create node with taxonomy filed.

Comment: Yes I can send term as well in json. Please Post your solution. Thanku

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the Json format to create node having taxonomy filed

```
{"title":"my act for tax","type":"activity","field_activity_type":{"und":"termname"}}
```

Comment: @Krishna.. I have posted one more question. Its related to deletion of a file from node using services. When I hit my url (mysite/endpoint/file/fid) with DELETE method it returns me status 200 ok but in actual the file is still there and so it has'nt been deleted. Can you please help me in this issue too.

Comment: Did you check your sever logs?

Comment: Yes I checked my server Log.. There is no error.

Comment: The file may not be deleted on disk: is it deleted from the managed file table?